# How to use React Router to pass data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to understand how to pass data using React Router in my situation of using a form. I am currently creating a workout app and one of my pages is a survey for the user to fill out. Once the user has filled this survey out the data would be passed on to a file called `personalExercise.js`. In this personalExercise file, I would use conditional rendering to determine where the user is best suited per their preference.

Description of the attempted action:

Step 1). The user would answer the questions in the survey (from the file `question.js`) and the answers would be submitted to the console.

Step2).
Once the questions are submitted the data would be passed on to a file(file called `personalExercise.js`), where conditional rendering would be used to send the user to a page set to their exercise type.

Ex.   In question.js file a user selects:

1. Male
2. 18-28
3. Stay Active

- The data then is transferred to the file personalExercise.js
  Where through a conditional statement, the user would be sent to a specific page.
  Ex. `if (gender === male && userAge === young && goals === loose weight) { return (page specified to user) }`

This is an idea and I am trying to use react Router to perform this task. Google has been my friend and enemy during my research.

```
import React from 'react';
import Introduction from './components/introduction';
import Questions from './components/beginning';
import Male from './components/questions';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

 export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path= "/" element={<Introduction />} />
        <Route path="/beginning" element= {<Questions />} />
        <Route path="/questions" element= {<Male />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

PersonalExercise

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

//purpose: To have the user see their specific exercises.

function personalExercise(formData) {

}


// function workout(){

// }
```

Questions

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';


export default function Questions() {
    
    const[formData, setFormData] = useState({
        gender: "", 
        userAge: "", 
        goals:"", 
    });

    function handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target;
       setFormData(prevFormData => {
        return {
            ...prevFormData,
            [name]: type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value 
        };
       });
    }

    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(formData)
       };

    return (
        <>
        <header>Questions</header>

        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>What was your gender at birth</legend>
                <input 
                type='radio'
                id = 'male'
                name = 'gender' 
                value = 'male'
                checked={formData.gender === "male"}
                onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="male"> Male </label>
                <br />

                <input 
                type='radio'
                id='female'
                name='gender'
                value = 'female' 
                checked={formData.gender === "female"}
                onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="female"> Female </label>
                <br />
            </fieldset>

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>How old are you?</legend>

                        <input 
                        type='radio'
                        id="young"
                        name="userAge"
                        value="young"
                        checked={formData.userAge === "young"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="young"> 18-28 </label>
                        <br />

                        <input 
                        type='radio'
                        id="middleAged"
                        name="userAge"
                        value="middleAged"
                        checked={formData.userAge === "middleAged"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="middleAged"> 29-39 </label>
                        <br />

                        <input 
                        type='radio'
                        id="older"
                        name="userAge"
                        value="older"
                        checked={formData.userAge === "older"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="older"> 40-50 </label>
                        <br />

                        <input 
                        type='radio'
                        id="senior"
                        name="userAge"
                        value="senior"
                        checked={formData.userAge === "senior"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="senior"> 51+ </label>
                        <br />
                    </fieldset>
                    <br />

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>What kind of fitness would you prefer?</legend>

                        <input 
                        type="radio"
                        id="active"
                        name="goals"
                        value="active"
                        checked = {formData.goals === "active"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor='active'>To stay active!</label>
                        <br />

                        <input
                        type="radio"
                        id="weight"
                        name="goals"
                        value= "weight"
                        checked = {formData.goals === "weight"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="weight"> To loose weight</label>
                    </fieldset>
                    <br />

                    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
                    </Form>


                </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing in a function like this in *App.js*

```
export default function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState({})

  const getData = (data) =>{ 
    setData(data)
  }
      
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path= "/" element={<Introduction />} />
        <Route path="/beginning" element={<Questions getData={getData}/>} />
        <Route path="/personalExercise" element={<personalExercise data={data}/>} />
        <Route path="/questions" element= {<Male />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Then in your *questions.js* you can use the function like this

```
export default function Questions(props) {

   function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        props.getData(formData)
       };
}
```

And to access the data in *personalExercise.js* you can call **props.data** like this

```
export default function personalExercise(props){

  return (
    <>
      {props.data}//whatever you want to conditionally render
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just a small thing, calling a function that does `setData` with the name of `getData` is very bad in my opinion as it does the opposite of what it says. Also, React components should be uppercase so `PersonalExercise` and not `personalExercise`.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I have added the provided code above in my code and it has made a huge difference! I have an error that says the following:
 Uncaught TypeError: props.getData is not a function
and I am trying to figure out what would cause this error, if you guys have any advice please let me know other than that, I am also trying to figure out my conditional statement with multiple radio buttons. You guys have mad ea huge difference in my code. Thank you!!